# javascript, node, grunt - How to debug (sigmund.js minimatch.js `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, gruntjs, bower

I am trying to run [this app to explore social media more graphically](https://github.com/ngageoint/social-media-picture-explorer-ui).

Within the README, when following the [Steps to get you up and running](https://github.com/ngageoint/social-media-picture-explorer-ui#steps-to-get-you-up-and-running-), I'm getting an error when running `grunt serve`:

```
~/git/social-media-picture-explorer-ui $ grunt serve
~/git/social-media-picture-explorer-ui/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/sigmund/sigmund.js:20
});
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at ~/git/social-media-picture-explorer-ui/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js:38:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/git/social-media-picture-explorer-ui/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js:1057:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

I know a little JavaScript, but I can't work out how to debug this error; I've tried looking for the `Unexpected token )` in `sigmund.js:20` (I believe this means line 20), `minimatch.js:38:15` (line 38 character 15) and `minimatch.js:1057:3` with no joy (i.e. I can't see any "Unexpected token )" in this files - I can paste the lines below if you think it would help?).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: if you `git clone`d the repo, you should `grunt build` it before trying to `grunt serve`. ref https://github.com/ngageoint/social-media-picture-explorer-ui#steps-to-get-you-up-and-running-

Comment: @mh-cbon - Thanks for your response, but unfortunately `grunt build` yields exactly the same error.

Comment: which node version do you run ? Did you try latest ? take a look into [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: `$ node -v` yeilds `v4.4.4`, which I believe is the latest.

Comment: I d check also sigmund.js code content, the module has not changed since 2012, that would mean you dled a corrupeted package. Is it possible ? I never faced that problem. see https://github.com/isaacs/sigmund/blob/master/sigmund.js

Comment: hm yes, it s the latest LTS indeed.

Comment: Thanks @mh-cbon comparing the sigmund.js you linked to the one I had, it turned out I was missing a load of lines (must have become corrupted as you mention). However I seem to have come across another problem (see edit in main question - in fact I'll leave this as only this problem, to keep it clear in case anyone else comes along). Thanks again!! (wonder what caused it to become corrupt though?)

Comment: looks like you are  missing something in your gruntfile? like , } ; ? can you post your gruntfile?